# Plotting behaviour of factor levels with ggraph::geom_edge_link()

Tags: r, networking, bipartite, ggraph

I'm having an issue with the order edges are plotted with ggraph::geom_edge_link() - I need them to respect the order of factor levels (factor cat below) and to have different widths according to value in strength.(I've already tried to understand if this is a bug @ggraph Github, but so far had no feedback ([#279](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph/issues/279))

I would expect edges to be plotted in the same "order" they appear in the edge list that feeds tbl_graph but that does not seem to be the case - what should be the expected behaviour?

#### Consider the following dataframe

```
    from <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","E","E","F","F","G","G","G","G","G","G")
    to <- c("H","I","I","J","O","O","H","I","I","N","N","H","N","J","H","J","J","I","I","J","L","N","J","L","H","L","H","M","J","N","I","H","H")
    cat <- c("weak","moderate","strong","v_strong","weak","moderate","strong","v_strong","weak","moderate","strong","v_strong","weak","weak","weak","weak","weak","weak","moderate","strong","v_strong","moderate","moderate","moderate","moderate","strong","v_strong","weak","weak","weak","weak","strong","v_strong")
    strength <- c(0.7,1,0.4,0.9,0,0,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.5,0.3,1,0.5,0.6,0.2,0.5,0.7,1,0,0.2,0.8,0.5,0.4,0.1,0,0.7,0.2,0.5,0.7,0.3,0.4,0.6)
    
    df <- data.frame(from, to, cat, strength)
    
    glimpse(df)

Rows: 33
Columns: 4
$ from     <chr> "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"...
$ to       <chr> "H", "I", "I", "J", "O", "O", "H", "I", "I", "N", "N", "H"...
$ cat      <fct> weak, moderate, strong, v_strong, weak, moderate, strong, ...
$ strength <dbl> 0.7, 1.0, 0.4, 0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3...
```

#### Now I order the factors

```
df$cat <- factor(df$cat, levels = c("weak", "moderate", "strong", "v_strong"))

levels(df$cat)

[2] "weak"     "moderate" "strong"   "v_strong"
```

#### The edge list

```
edge.list <- df
```

#### The node list

```
n.from <- df %>%
   group_by(from) %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   rename(name = from)
 
n.to <- df %>%
  group_by(to) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  rename(name = to)
 
node.list <- rbind(n.from, n.to)
```

#### The tbl_graph file

```
Netw <- tbl_graph(nodes = node.list, edges = edge.list)
```

#### Now when I plot it

```
ggraph(Netw) +
 geom_edge_link(aes(edge_colour = cat, width = strength)) +
 scale_edge_width_continuous(limits = c(0,1), range=c(.1,2.5)) +
 scale_edge_colour_manual(values = c("moderate" = "grey80", "weak" = "red", "very strong" = "#3E1404", "strong" = "#9F6B39"))
```

#### I obtain this:

[image]

I would expect the red edges (corresponding to the weak category) to be plotted in the back and not at the front

I tried different things (e.g. using `as.character(cat)`, different orders, remove strength, even merging weak with moderate creates the same output) but am getting always the same result. I just don't understand if this is the expected behaviour and how I can obtain my desired output. Any help would be great!

I am using ggraph_2.0.4 in R R version 4.0.3

Thanks!